# Question received Tumbleweed badge. Shall I delete it?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, tumbleweed-badge

I have a question which just got me the Tumbleweed badge. I was wondering if I could delete my question. One reason is I found the answer and I have previously answered some of my questions, so it won't be nice to do that again. Second, no one even saw the question. Why must a point be deducted when we delete a question? And can you delete a Tumbleweed question?

Comment: It's no different than any other question. Deleting it won't take away your badge.

Comment: If you found the answer, why not just post an actual answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no reason to delete your question. And [it is explicitly encouraged to answer your own questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/166308) (even when you know the answer at the time of asking!!). So you don't have to worry that it will not be nice. Quite the opposite! Go and answer it and accept your answer.

Comment: Well Thanks I think its because i am doing Vb6 Migration and not alot of people is doing that. Thanks for the enouragement

Comment: Exactly! Not many people are doing that, but when do, they will find your answer! That's exactly the point of community sharing, @shaikibrahim

Answer (score 1):

There are some niche tags where you can wait longer before you receive an answer. Some of my questions got an answer after a few months. In some cases I wasn't doing anything anymore with the technologies I had asked about :)

Well, the tumbleweed is exactly what it's name stays for. Just weep the tears and learn to be patient. If it was for deleting questions, it would be called rubber or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

My question that earned me tumbleweed is actually my most viewed question of anything I have ever asked.  Go ahead and answer it yourself and you'll be surprised how helpful it may become to people.

Comment: Yes, actually questions with full error message in title get most views, because this is the first thing people type in google! Including myself.

Answer (score 0):

What I did with my tumbleweed, when I did not knew an answer, was: put enough bounty on it to get it answered. Worked all right.