# Shall I delete TRIVIAL question that I answer myself?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I know that [answering my own questions is appreciated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/166308) (I was also [answering this to others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186787/166308)), but, what if the question is really trivial, so trivial it can be found in the manual? Shall I delete it?

I would delete it right away but I've heard that by deleting questions you might get penalized. But in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18058684/684229) no one has invested an effort in my question and probably never will...

**EDIT**: thank you for all your responses, they encouraged me to keep the question there. You are absolutely right it allmost surely will be useful to someone - because many people, as well as myself, when they have problem they start by typing it into google, instead of studying the docs. I've been sometimes downvoted for stating this approach but thats just how are fast society works. Google is faster than searching *any* docs, especially in combo with Stackoverflow...

Comment: I would say: "no". This was really a trivial mistake, but one that can be made by anyone (who lives in a country where the separator is `,`).

Comment: At least you came back and answered it, even if it was trivial. Better than than you just came back and added a comment saying "OK, forget about this I've solved it myself" and left it at that. *That* is the worst thing to do.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with keeping the question and answer around.

Comment: @CodyGray that's what JonW said ;)

Comment: thank you all for your responses, please see updated question for my response.

Answer (score 9):

Don't be *too* quick... but if you think it really is extremely trivial, that might not be a bad idea. If it isn't likely to be helpful, and is too basic, it wouldn't hurt to delete it, and it would save you from some potential future down votes. But just take a moment to consider if the question and answer would be useful to someone who had already done some due-diligence searching.

As for deletion causing you to be penalized, I wouldn't worry about that at your stage. Deletion in and of itself doesn't hurt (it's the secondary effect that deletion causes), but you have too much decent content for that to hurt you. *Way too much* :)

Comment: thanks Andrew, please follow my question for response

Answer (score 5):

I think if you want to delete it, that is OK, but I would leave it the way it is.
The question is well formatted and as you mentioned, there is no problem with answering your own question.

I think other people may have the same question you did. Many questions on Stack Overflow are trivial and they can be found in manuals/books, but they are still useful as a shortcut.

Besides, your reputation speaks for itself. If the fact that your question was trivial bothers you, you'll know to be more cautious next time.

Comment: This is correct. There is no set criteria that determines if the OP should delete it. It's ultimately up to them. **Just like votes**. If the OP wants to delete it, that's there thing. We shouldn't decide for them. It's pretty much just ethics (I think). Voting is your thing. If you downvote a good question or answer, you pay the price of a -1 and a user of the community suffers a -2. If you delete a good question, that's your thing. You pay the price. If you need to reference it again, tough luck. The community loses a good question though.

Comment: Thanks Andre, see my updated question for response. Your second paragraph is exactly what I think! Though many will bash me for this approach, Google->Stackoverflow is always faster than looking into the docs :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you think the answer will be useful to others, leave it.

If you think it won't be useful to anyone else then delete it.

If you're not sure if it will be useful to others then wait a short while, see how many views it gets and what votes it gets; if the responses are positive (it gets some views and positive votes) then leave it; it's likely to help some people.  If it gets virtually no views, or mostly negative votes when it's viewed, then the community seems to think it's not helpful content; unless you feel strongly that it will be useful for some users despite this, it's probably best to just delete it.

Comment: -1 for encouraging deletion in certain cases. The only reason to delete it now is if it is badly written, on the verge of closing, etc. NOT because it's not of use to anyone. I've ran into many problems that I think no one else could have, then I Google and come here and _there's an answer_. I mean, it's like _magic_, amirite?

Comment: @ColeJohnson And the reason that you'd want to delete the question in the cases you just gave is precisely because the question wouldn't be of use to anyone.  The fact that it's poorly written would just be a reason it's not useful to anyone, and that it's about to be closed is just a potential indicator that others feel that it wouldn't be useful to anyone.  As I myself stated, you can rely on those indicators if you don't know if it will be useful.  Note I didn't say that you should delete a question just because it's not useful to you, but rather if it wouldn't be useful to *anyone*.

Comment: I remember with the old close reasons, questions that wouldn't be of use to _anyone_ were close as (I believe) too localized. Now with these new close reasons, the text isn't meant strictly (as evident by my two "rethinking audit selection" questions).

Comment: @ColeJohnson There are a large number of reasons that a question might not be useful to anyone else.  Having a very narrow scope (i.e. "too localized") is one possibility.  Another is that the question is just so garbled that it's just not understandable.  Another is that the information is easily accessible elsewhere already (possibly on the same site, possibly not).  There are many other reasons beyond even those.  Note that there is a difference (in degree) from deleting another's question vs deleting your own.

Comment: +1 for encouraging deletion in certain cases.

Comment: @Servy but if it's answerable, then it _can_ be edited to _not_ be garbled.

Comment: @ColeJohnson What?  Where did I say that such a question *would* be answerable?

Comment: You didn't. The OP did. He asked, if he asks a question and finds the answer on his own, should he post an answer or delete the question. I was referencing that. If the question is illegible, but you can deduce what they meant from an answer, _you_ could **edit** the question to _make it legible_.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Potentially, yes.  Assuming the answer is legible.  Clearly that's not the issue here, I was discussing the general case of reasons any question might be deleted, moving beyond this one example.  A question might be deleted because it's illegible, it may not even have an answer.

Comment: @Servy in that case, if the OP hasn't come back and helped himself, then we should delete it. Your answer read to me as if we should delete it just because it wouldn't be useful to anyone. My argument to that was that I've experience problems that I thought _no one_ else would experience. This site proved me wrong many times. Just because you don't think it'll be useful to anyone doesn't mean anything. If the community thinks it does by not downvoting it or by up voting it, then we should keep it. If you want to edit your answer to address my argument, I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @ColeJohnson My post is specifically *not* addressing the case of people deleting another's post.  It is specifically addressing the case of when you should delete your *own* post.  You should delete your own post if you feel that it won't be useful to anyone else.  I described how, if you're not sure if your post will be useful to others, how you can help determine it's usefulness (i.e. relying on votes).  If your experience has shown that you aren't a good judge of what others will find useful, feel free to err on the side of not deleting, but the site's goal is as I stated.

Comment: @Servy it appears we are having a miscommunication. I never intended it to sound like we should delete other's question in a situation like the OP's. I was referring to illegible questions that the OP abandons. He asks the question then never comes back. Those we should delete.

Comment: @ColeJohnson And I specifically said that I'm not discussing such cases at all.  They are entirely offtopic and none of my statements apply to such cases at all.  I'm intentionally not bringing up such cases to avoid confusion about talking about self-deletion and deletion of other's content at the same time.